# How to save latest offset that Spark consumed to ZK or Kafka and can read back after restart

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am using `Kafka 0.8.2` to receive data from AdExchange then I use `Spark Streaming 1.4.1` to store data to `MongoDB`.

My problem is when I restart my `Spark Streaming` Job for instance like update new version, fix bug, add new features. It will continue read the latest `offset` of `kafka` at the time then I will lost data AdX push to kafka during restart the job.

I try something like `auto.offset.reset -> smallest` but it will receive from 0 -> last then data was huge and duplicate in db.

I also try to set specific `group.id` and `consumer.id` to `Spark` but it the same.

How to save the latest `offset` spark consumed to `zookeeper` or `kafka` then can read back from that to latest `offset`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of the constructors of createDirectStream function can get a map that will hold the partition id as the key and the offset from which you are starting to consume as the value.

Just look at api here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html
The map that I was talking about usually called: fromOffsets

You can insert data to the map:

```
startOffsetsMap.put(TopicAndPartition(topicName,partitionId), startOffset)
```

And use it when you create the direct stream:

```
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder, (String, String)](
                streamingContext, kafkaParams, startOffsetsMap, messageHandler(_))
```

After each iteration you can get the processed offsets using:

```
rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
```

You would be able to use this data to construct the fromOffsets map in the next iteration.

You can see the full code and usage here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html at the end of the page

Comment: But How to save latest offset consumed to ZK or Kafka. I try to enable `kafkaParams ++= Map[String, String]("auto.commit.interval.ms" -> "1000")
    kafkaParams ++= Map[String, String]("zookeeper.sync.time.ms" -> "200")
    kafkaParams ++= Map[String, String]("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms" -> "400")` but it not work

Comment: One of the options is as I told you to use the .offsetRanges data structure. After you processed your stream in a given iteration you can do:

`dStream.foreachRDD { rdd => val x = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges; // Do something with X (save it external FS for example) }` x will hold the last processed offset for every topic-partition combination of the RDD.
If you need to have exactly once semantics, you would have to support it manually, but it is possible.

Comment: My idea that I don't want to save in external storage because ZK and Kafka can handle this.

Comment: I believe they can't. Spark 1.3.1 change its approach about how to use Kafka as data source from Write Ahead Logs to direct streams. Direct stream uses Kafka SimpleConsumer to get messages from Kafka.

And you can read here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example
that one of the down sides of using SimpleConsumer is that you have to keep track yourself for the offsets that you already consumed.

As long as Spark streaming uses simple consumer you won't find a solution from Kafka / ZK perspective. But Spark may add their own handling on top of Kafka.

Comment: so we need store offset in external storage? Is Redis suitable? Thanks.

Comment: Any reliable storage should do the work. I'm usually saving the data to HDFS because I think it is the most simple solution. I can't think of a reason why Redis won't be able to do the work as well.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Michael Kopaniov's answer, if you really want to use ZK as the place you store and load your map of offsets from, you can.

However, because your results are not being output to ZK, you will not get reliable semantics unless your output operation is idempotent (which it sounds like it isn't).

If it's possible to store your results in the same document in mongo alongside the offsets in a single atomic action, that might be better for you.

For more detail, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXnNEq1v3VA

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code you can use to store offsets in ZK http://geeks.aretotally.in/spark-streaming-kafka-direct-api-store-offsets-in-zk/

And here's some code you can use to use the offset when you call KafkaUtils.createDirectStream:
http://geeks.aretotally.in/spark-streaming-direct-api-reusing-offset-from-zookeeper/

Comment: Both of these links are now broken, which is why the community always suggests posting the solution as part of the answer along with the link, not just the link.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't figured this out 100% yet, but your best bet is probably to set up JavaStreamingContext.checkpoint().

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing for an example.

According to some blog entries *https://github.com/koeninger/kafka-exactly-once/blob/master/blogpost.md* there are some caveats but it almost feels like it involves certain fringe cases that are only alluded to and not actually explained.

Comment: Checkpointing is the right way to go incase you don't make any change to your StreamingContext since then you would be able to continue the processing from the right offset automatically (Spark will take care for that).
If you want to add features / correct bugs (And apparently giaosudau want to do it) very often you are going to change the streaming context and therefore wan't be able to use the checkpoints directory. The last link that you provided explains it perfectly.

Comment: @MichaelKopaniov is there any way to checksum the context function and invalidate the previous context if the function has changed? In which case it would fall back to reading offsets from a store (fs, database)

Comment: @Stephane Few days passed since I dealt with this problem so I may be mistaken but as far as I remember in the old Spark streaming (<2.0) You either create a new StreamingContext or you read a StreamingContext that was previously defined from the checkpoint directory.
You do not create a new StreamingContext for every iteration and just compare it with the context from the checkpoint directory, So if I understood your question correctly, you can't invalidate previously saved context.

Comment: @Stephane but what you can do, is to have some configurable parameter that indicates whether you want to use the streaming context from the checkpoint directory or you would like to create a new one of your own. If this parameter specifies that you want to create a new context, then you will create if from (fs, database) and override the previous context when checkpointing the data to the checkpoint directory.

Comment: Not the same - from the doc: "If you enable Spark checkpointing, offsets will be stored in the checkpoint. This is easy to enable, but there are drawbacks. Your output operation must be idempotent, since you will get repeated outputs; transactions are not an option. Furthermore, you cannot recover from a checkpoint if your application code has changed. For planned upgrades, you can mitigate this by running the new code at the same time as the old code (since outputs need to be idempotent anyway, they should not clash). But for unplanned failures that require code changes, you will lose data.."